# Why is Rails Console command (rails c) not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what happens when I input the `rails console` command:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 29953
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    37: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    36: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    35: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    34: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
    33: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    32: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
    31: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
    30: from /home/ubuntu/tickit-app25/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    28: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    27: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    26: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    25: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    23: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    22: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    21: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    20: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    19: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
    18: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
    17: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@tod/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
    16: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:381:in `start'
    15: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:381:in `new'
    14: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:410:in `initialize'
    13: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:410:in `new'
    12: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/context.rb:91:in `initialize'
    11: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/extend-command.rb:242:in `save_history='
    10: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:45:in `save_history='
     9: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `init_save_history'
     8: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `extend'
     7: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:65:in `extended'
     6: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `load_history'
     5: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
     4: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
     3: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block in load_history'
     2: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `each'
     1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in load_history'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `<<': string contains null byte (ArgumentError)

.irbrc file not found
```

Comment: Check your HISTORY_FILE - it seems as if during the loading it gets something unexpected.

Comment: I deleted the history from the terminal but not work rails c

Comment: Can you also check if the file is read from other places? it could either read it from working directory or home directory.